# search value in excel using Linq

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I am searching value using linq in my ASP webform C# project. here is my code:

```
            var searchCell = from cell in worksheet1.Cells["B:B"] 
                             where cell.Value.ToString() == "something"
                             select cell.Start.Row;


            if (searchCell!=null)
            {
                rowNum = searchCell.First();
                StatusLabel.Text = rowNum.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "None";
            }
```

the code is working fine if the search text is found. However, when I try to search for word "something" it doesnt exist in the file, but it doesnt go into "else" condition, but error in the "if" condition. What is the result for my searchCell when it cant find the text? isn't it null?
anyone knows how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LINQ query returns a sequence of objects, never `null`. If the sequence is empty, your call to `First()` will fail. Try this:

```
if (searchCell.Any())
{
    rowNum = searchCell.First();
    StatusLabel.Text = rowNum.ToString();
}
else
{
    StatusLabel.Text = "None";
}
```